# Windows Store App fails certification with optimizations turned off?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, compiler-optimization

I have a rather particular thing I'm doing. (testing IL transforms within Windows Store apps)... so pardon if this sounds weird and please avoid just telling me "turn optimizations on"

Anyway, I came into a very odd problem when trying to certify a blank windows store application. All I did was create it, modify it's Release configuration to not use optimizations, and then build it into a package. When trying to certify this package though, I get this error:

> Debug Configuration Test
>
> The binary App1.exe is built in debug mode.

Obviously, enabling debugging and disabling optimizations is two different things... aren't they? Is this a bug in the certification utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the application certification process appears to just blindly look for a .pdb file. This file is generated by default when code isn't optimized. Going into the "advanced" menu of the build settings in Visual Studio, there is an option for Debug Info. Changing it to "none" fixed this problem for me.